# Refreshing or rebuilding flutter widget after it has been fully initialised

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to make a Telegram client for android using the tdlib flutter port. I am currently attempting to make a contact list of sorts, by requesting it from telegram and making a listview of textbuttons.

The only issue is that since the library is async, I get the contact list after the layout has been initialized. Is it possible to somehow rebuild the layout or update it to make the list load properly.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fima/services/telegram_service.dart';
import 'package:tdlib/td_api.dart' show TdError;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:tdlib/td_api.dart' as TdApi;

class ContactListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactListScreenState createState() => _ContactListScreenState();
  }



class _ContactListScreenState extends State<ContactListScreen> {
  final String title = 'Contact list';
  bool _loadingStep = false;
  String _Error;
  String route = "initRoute";
  List<TextButton> contacts = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getContacts(onError: _handelError,);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text(title),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xD3232323),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child:
          ListView (
            children: contacts,
          ),
      ),
    );

  }

  Future _getContacts(
      {
        void Function(TdError) onError,
      }) async {
    final result = await context.read<TelegramService>().send(
      TdApi.GetContacts(
      ),
    );
    if (result is TdError && onError != null) {
      onError(result);
    }
    TdApi.Users users = result;
    for (var i = 0; i < users.totalCount; i++) {
      final result = await context.read<TelegramService>().send(
        TdApi.GetUser(userId: users.userIds[i]),
      );
      TdApi.User user = result;
      print(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName);
      final contact = TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print("Test");
          },
          child: Text(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName),
      );
      setState(() {
        contacts.add(contact);
      });
    }

  }

  void _handelError(TdError error) async {
    setState(() {
      _loadingStep = false;
      _Error = error.message;
    });
  }



}
```

I have attempted to use setState, but without much success, could anyone be so kind as to provide me with the solution to this problem?

Comment: Use `FutureBuilder` where your `ListView` is and call `_getContacts` from the `FutureBuilder` `future:` field instead of from initState. You can return your `ListView` from `FutureBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `FutureBuilder` might help. It is a widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Future.

You can modify your build to return a FutureBuilder something like this:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _getContacts, 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.hasData) {
              //Use snapshot data to build by returning your Container with List
     }
     else{
             //Return a CircularProgressIndicator
     }
  }
}
```

Refer the documentation on the FutureBuilder class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, the problem is that "future:" requires Future<String> to be returned as far as I see.

Comment: You can use the FutureBuilder to return the `ListView.builder`.

Comment: I believe this article might help. Chech it [here](https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9)

Comment: The argument type 'Future<List<TextButton>> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List<TextButton>>'.